# IOS application got rejected for App Store Review Guideline 2.5.1

Tags: ios, app-store

We have just got a rejection on an AppStore application commiting.
   Here is the message that Apple gave:
  [image: apple message]
  
   Apple said we use NEVPNManager in an unapproved manner. but I am sure that
our code do not use any function of NEVPNManager. Then, I thought that must
be some 3rd party SDK use NEVPNManager, However, after checking our project
setting, I am sure we don't link "NetworkExtension.framework" and don't open
"NetExtension" capabitity, so there is no way to use NEVPNManager.
   I am very confused about this, so I want to get some advice about this problem.

[appstore-guidelines-software-requirements](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements)
[networkextension-nevpnmanager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager)

Comment: did you get any answer?

Comment: Same issue with me, Have you gotten the solution yet??